# Dispose of thread-unsafe native resources

Tags: c#, thread-safety, dispose

Before I start explaining I'll mention that I am unable to find any related posts to my issue on google, so this is not a duplicate post.

Alright, so my problem is:

I am creating a **wrapper** for a **Native API** that has resources that are **thread-unsafe** and I need to dispose of the resources when the object is no longer used.
Normally you create a Dispose method for that, you release your unmanaged resources there but if its NOT called? well... normally what happens is that the **finalizer (destructor) calls the Dispose method for you** and that's my issue! The finalizer is executed on a different thread than the native resource is created from! That causes the API to return a error code, leaving the native resource untouched! So what should I do?

My idea of solving the problem:

I think what I could do is create the Dispose method like normal and dispose of the native resource there, but **when Dispose method is called, check if its called from the proper thread, otherwise throw a exception!** and **if Dispose method wasn't called and it goes out of scope then throw a exception in the destructor** causing the C# application to **crash** with a described reason in the exception.

So what should I do? What would be the best option? Normally the garbage collector would take care of that, but not in this case.

Comment: Yep.  Not calling Dispose() is a bug, and crashing is an appropriate response.  In fact throwing an exception (or at least logging a warning) is about the only thing you should ever do in a finalizer.

Comment: Thank you, I see that as the only option as well, but is there really no other way? Maybe some good way to notify the developer that its important to call Dispose? (Not at runtime) or allow the garbage collector to do at least something? Taking a look at System.Drawing.Graphics class that has a window HDC which is thread-unsafe does seem that this is the only way, but the difference is that the Graphics class doesn't cause a crash when dispose is forgotten. Edit: Alright, so the finalizer would be the notifier.

Comment: There is a "good way to notify the developer that it's important to call Dispose".  You implement IDisposable. That's why it exists.

Comment: Have you looked up the SafeHandle class?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2